# Sending data through post request and returning processed values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a html page(index.html) where once the user clicks on the submit button, the form will process the POST method and sends all my data to the php side(index.php) to process the data. Once the php is done processing my data, it is suppose to return the processed data to the same HTML document but I cant figure out how to do that.

Basically the flow is

- index.html -> input and submit form (POST)
- processOrder.php ->process the information only (user does not see this page)
- back to index.html with table of processed data (user is updated with table)

This is my javascript file

```
 function isNumber(idValue,evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var sum = 0;
    var costOfApple = 0;
    var costOfOrange = 0;
    var costOfBananna = 0;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        document.getElementById(idValue.id).value = "";
        document.getElementById('totalCost').value = "Nan";
        $("#invalid-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
        $("#invalid-alert").slideUp(500);
});
    }
    else
    {
        costOfApple = document.getElementById('apple').value *69;
        costOfOrange = document.getElementById('orange').value *59;
        costOfBananna = document.getElementById('bananna').value *39;
        sum = (Number(costOfApple) + Number(costOfOrange) + Number(costOfBananna)) /100;
        document.getElementById('totalCost').value = "$" + (sum).toFixed(2);
}
}
```

This is my php file which processes the data (I cant figure out how to return these data back to my html page)

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name; $totalCost; $appleNo; $orangeNo; $banannaNo; $appleCost; $orangeCost; $banannaCost; $paymentMethod = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $paymentMethod = $_POST["payment"];
    $appleNo = $_POST["apple"];
    $orangeNo = $_POST["orange"];
    $banannaNo = $_POST["bananna"];
    $appleCost = $appleNo * 0.69;
    $orangeCost = $orangeNo * 0.59;
    $banannaCost = $banannaNo * 0.39;

    if ($paymentMethod == "Mastercard") {
    $totalCost = ($appleCost + $orangeCost + $banannaCost) *100.12/100 ;
}
    else if ($paymentMethod == "Visa"){
    $totalCost = ($appleCost + $orangeCost + $banannaCost) *100.13/100 ;
}
  else{
    $totalCost = ($appleCost + $orangeCost + $banannaCost) *100.105/100 ;
}
$totalCost =  number_format($totalCost,2);
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use ajax to request to your php process and your php will return something in this call.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp
If you use jQuery:
$.ajax({
  url: "index.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { name : 'Test' }
});
This page may help you: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: What exactly is the `isNumber` function is supposed to do?

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata it checks whether the input is a numerical value

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a header at the end of your processOrder.php to direct you to your page and saving your index.html to index.php so you can echo back results.

```
 header("Location: index.php");
```

You can also include the page at the end of your processOrder.php to direct you to your page.

```
include 'index.php';
exit();
```

You can pass data through setting up a session.  place session_start() at the beginning of your php code then set variables to the session. Do this for each variable to carry over.

```
if ($YourMYSQLResults){                                                                               
$_SESSION['CustomName'] = $CustomData;                                                                   

}
```

Comment: how do i pass the values back to this index.php file?

Answer (score 0):

To send the data back to `index.php` from `processOrder.php` you will want to look at the PHP super global `'$_SESSION'` variable.

**Link:** [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Basic usage below:

**processOrder.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 /*
         Your Code............................
 */
 $_SESSION['totalCost'] = $totalCost;
?>
```

Make sure you start the session on each page before assigning values to a session variable.

Once you have assigned a value to a session variable you will be able to use it on other pages like so:

**index.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['totalCost'];
 ?>
```

Sessions normally shutdown automatically when PHP is finished executing a script, but can be manually shutdown using the session_write_close() function.